# rosserial does not work on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric

Tags: rosserial, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to install ros. Only the ros-electric-common could be installed (not the desktop version) but I thought this may be enough for rosserial (To try with my Arduino communication).

But there is a dependancy-problem. Could not install rosserial because I was missing geometry, which can not be loaded because the package libglut3-dev is replaced by freeglut3-dev (see ticket 4963 from 5 months ago).

Could a developer change this dependency please, or give me a workaround for this problem, so I can use my Arduino with ROS. This was the only dependency that was NOK so this would help me very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11623/rosserial-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric/) by [edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/1253/edward/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-21**:
Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/2505/installing-ros-diamondback-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debs are still building for much of 11.10 -- these issues will get worked out.

Also, for future note, it is probably more helpful to note that you have a problem with "geometry" not "rosserial". rosserial is one of many, many packages that depend on geometry, but the rosserial developers are not going to be able to help you fix a problem with geometry building (and geometry is a legitimate dependency of rosserial).

If you want to temporarily build rosserial on a broken ROS install, you could do the following:

1. Do a source checkout of rosserial (using hg).
2. Edit rosserial_arduino/CMakeLists.txt and rosserial_arduino/manifest.xml to remove references to geometry_msgs.
3. Run "make" in that local folder (make sure rosserial is on your ROS package path).

Note that none of the examples that use geometry_msgs will work.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two main broken dependencies for installing electric (with the natty repository) in oneiric:

libglut3-dev (needed for geometry funcionality)
libopencv2.3-dev (needed for vision functionality)

The first one can be easily (and temporally)solved installing manually libglut3-dev:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/libglut3-dev

Then electric-desktop and some basic functionality can be installed. However the electric-desktop-full cannot be installed due to the second broken dependency. A temporal solution can be install libopencv2.3-dev from some ppa like: [https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/opencv2.3](https://launchpad.net/%7Egijzelaar/+archive/opencv2.3)

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2011-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a workaround. I described what worked for me [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2505/installing-ros-diamondback-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric?answer=4320#4320).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1